# Getting "Bad Request" for Postman API

Tags: postman

I simply took an example from [Postman API Documentation](https://docs.api.getpostman.com/#99810ef3-3cc0-a6cc-06f5-d8e2ae9d84e4) for Create Collection and removed the extra request outside the folder.

My intention is to create just a folder with 1 request in it.

Here is the request:

```
{
    "collection":{
       "variables":[

       ],
       "info":{
          "name":"Sample Collection",
          "description":"This is just a sample collection.",
          "schema":"https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.0.0/collection.json"
       },
       "item":[
          {
             "name":"This is a folder",
             "description":"",
             "item":[
                {
                   "name":"Sample POST Request",
                   "request":{
                      "url":"echo.getpostman.com/post",
                      "method":"POST",
                      "header":[
                         {
                            "key":"Content-Type",
                            "value":"application/json",
                            "description":""
                         }
                      ],
                      "body":{
                         "mode":"raw",
                         "raw": "{
                            \"data\": \"123\"
                        }"
                      },
                      "description":"This is a sample POST Request"
                   },
                   "response":[

                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

But for this, I am getting "Bad Request" error, what exactly is wrong with my request?

EDIT - [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13b7p6vUcWJG1fvVWBmeTBw2twArWvQzB/view?usp=sharing) what it looks like in Postman

Comment: What does this request look like in the Postman UI - Can you update the question with an Image. Could you also confirm the full URL that you are using in the POST request.

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: Might be the device that i’m using but when I zoom in, it becomes very distorted.

Comment: It appeared distorted even on my computer. No idea why. I added a google drive link for screenshot, please check the same.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you’re trying to send the whole `collection` json file back to that route.

The JSON in the request body on the image is what you would import into Postman to get the `Sample Collection` folder. This contains a request called `Sample POST Request`

Copy the request body JSON and save it as a `.json` file - Then import this using the `Import` feature in the top left on the application.

[image: Import]

This will then create the folder for you in the application with the sample POST request.

If you send it to the `echo` URL, you will receive a response telling you that the URL has now changed to `https://postman-echo.com/post` - Add this new URL into the address bar and hit `Send`.

[image: Postman]